# Change hidden field Value with jquery and get the new value in server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I change value off the hidden field with jquery and now i want to get the new value in server.
i use asp.net and this is my jquery code:

```
$('#HiddenField').val("NewValue");
```

and this is my html tag:

```
<input id="HiddenField" type="hidden" runat="server" value=""/>
```

in my page i change the value of the `'#HiddenField'` and i want to get the NewValue in server side.

Comment: Please include relevant parts of your server side code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried with this on my page,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="goBtn" Text="Go" OnClick="goBtn_Click" />
        <input id="HiddenField" type="hidden" runat="server" value="" />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="testTxt"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=HiddenField.ClientID %>').val("Test");
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this in the code behind,

```
protected void goBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testTxt.Text = HiddenField.Value;
}
```

when you press the go button, the new value is available on the server.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the ClientID of your hidden field in the JQuery selector such as:

```
$('#<%= HiddenField.ClientID %>').val("NewValue");
```

Or, alternatively, use a style for the hidden field and access it by the class, such as:

```
<input id="HiddenField" type="hidden" runat="server" value="" CssClass="hidden"/>
$('.hidden').val("NewValue");
```

Comment: it change the value but i cant get this new value in server side.in the server side i get null

Comment: is the hidden field within the `form` tag, and are you checking the value on postback or callback??

Comment: post your code on how and in which event your trying to access the value. cant help you without code!